# Node.js %OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall - Runtime Function Error

Tags: node.js, v8

I am running Node v11.x.x, and receiving an error for a V8 runtime function.

```
let operand = 3;
function square() {
    return operand * operand;
}
square()
%OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall(square);
square()
```

Running with:

```
node --allow-natives-syntax -trace_opt -trace_deopt main.js
```

Recieving an error of

```
ReferenceError: OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall is not defined
```

I thought this runtime function was still included, or am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're relying on *automatic* `semicolon` insertion by `Javascript` (which fails your intention).

Your code without `;` translates to `modulo` operation which is a valid `JavaScript` operation so it has no reason to add a `;` for you after the first call `square()`.

```
square() % OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall(square);
```

Written this way (as `JavaScript` sees), it obviously looks like `modulo` operation. Now it's obvious why `OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall` is `undefined`.

Change your code to (Notice the `;`):

```
let operand = 3;
function square() {
  return operand * operand;
}
square(); // <-- here
%OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall(square);
square();
```

Here is a [*nice read*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/) by `T.J. Crowder` (SO user) on why you should not miss `;`